# Cocos2d game crashed with java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in android

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone

I am working on a game in android cocos2d.

Every thing is working fine except this random crash.

When I try to replace the scene it gives me exception below is the stack trace for the same:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:569)

at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCNode.onEnter(CCNode.java:1351)

at org.cocos2d.layers.CCLayer.onEnter(CCLayer.java:173)

at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCNode.onEnter(CCNode.java:1352)

at org.cocos2d.layers.CCLayer.onEnter(CCLayer.java:173)

at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCNode.onEnter(CCNode.java:1352)

at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCDirector.setNextScene(CCDirector.java:1238)

at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCDirector.drawCCScene(CCDirector.java:705)

at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCDirector.onDrawFrame(CCDirector.java:665)

at org.cocos2d.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1245)

at org.cocos2d.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1056)
```

Here is my code to replace the scene:

```
CCDirector.sharedDirector().replaceScene(GameLayer.scene(activityContext,null));
```

It works fine for some time but after a while it crashes and again starts working fine and then again after some time crashes.

Please suggest me some work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is indicating that a list is being modified while it is being iterated over.  Given the call stack, it appears that Cocos is iterating over the nodes in the scene to draw them.  It seems like a node is being added or removed from the scene while this is happening.

This could be because you are modifying the scene either:

1. In a drawing callback for a node; or
2. From a different thread (i.e. not the OpenGL thread), therefore racing with the drawing.

Check where you add or remove things from the scene to ensure it doesn't happen while drawing, and it is only done from the right thread (or with appropriate synchronisation).